# Kivy does not display actionbar

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I have the following code to create an actionbar:

Python Code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.actionbar import ActionBar

Window.clearcolor = (1, 1, 1, 1)

class Menu(ActionBar):
    pass


class TestApp(App):

def build(self):
    return design


design = Builder.load_file('test.kv')
```

and this is the kv code:

```
#: import ActionBar kivy.uix.actionbar

<Menu>:
    pos_hint: {'top': 1}
    ActionView:
        use_separator: True
        ActionPrevious:
            title: 'Action Bar'
            with_previous: False
        ActionButton:
            important: True
            text: 'Add'
        ActionButton:
            text: 'FAQ'
        ActionButton:
            text: 'Credits'
```

When I run the code above, it just presents a white window and closes immediately. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: please improve your indentation, in python is very important.

Comment: I did but it does not seem to answer my question :)

Comment: Who has told you that is the answer? If you want to get an answer, your question must be of quality, and in your case the code that shows has problems of indentation. read [ask] and review the [tour]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.lang import Builder

Window.clearcolor = (1, 1, 1, 1)

runTouchApp(Builder.load_file('test.kv'))
```

test.kv:

```
ActionBar:
    pos_hint: {'top':1}
    ActionView:
        use_separator: True
        ActionPrevious:
            title: 'Action Bar'
            with_previous: False
        ActionOverflow:
        ActionButton:
            icon: 'atlas://data/images/defaulttheme/audio-volume-high'
        ActionButton:
            important: True
            text: 'Important'
        ActionButton:
            text: 'Btn2'
        ActionButton:
            text: 'Btn3'
        ActionButton:
            text: 'Btn4'
        ActionGroup:
            text: 'Group1'
            ActionButton:
                text: 'Btn5'
            ActionButton:
                text: 'Btn6'
            ActionButton:
                text: 'Btn7'
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked like magic. Can you explain what does the runTouchApp does? I saw it on other projects too. Thanks :)

Comment: Hi @JezreelMartin, It is static main function that starts the application loop. And same way kivy.base.stopTouchApp() will stop the current application by leaving the main loop.